# how to determine the font size of the text from the height, in swift？

Tags: swift

I need to add a text watermark to the image. 
The height of the text varies with the height of the image. 
Now I know the height of the image, and I know the height of the text. 
How do I know the font size of the text?
In short, how to determine the font size of the text from the height？
Now my solution is as follows. Does anyone have a better way? 
Thanks!!!

```swift
/// - Parameter height: target height for font
 func textFontSize(from height: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        var fontSize: CGFloat = 30
        var textFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)

        while (textFont.lineHeight < (height * 4 / 5) ||
            textFont.lineHeight > height){

            //decrease font size
            if textFont.lineHeight > height {
                fontSize = fontSize - 0.5

            // increase
            }else if textFont.lineHeight < (height * 4 / 5) {
                fontSize = fontSize + 0.5
            }

            textFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)
        }
        return fontSize
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current solution?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson  I hope that the font size can be more accurate, so that the height can be more accurate, and then the efficiency is a bit low, so I want to find a better way.

Comment: Choosen a default font size, you can try using a ration between the text height and image height. For example, let's take 8 as default font size. Let's have image's height 100 and text's height 20. The ration will be 20/100 = 0.2, you can multiply your base font size with this factor*10 -> `newFontSize = baseFontSize * ratio * 10`. Using the previous example, you will have -> `newFontSize = 8 * 0,2 * 10 = 16`. Obviously, if this is too much or too less, you can adjust the ratio.

Comment: @Andrew21111 Thanks for your answer!  But your method is wrong. default font size is 8, newFontSize = 8 * 0,2 * 10 = 16, if default font size is 20, ratio must bigger than 0.2, newFontSize must bigger than 16, so same target hight, but Different newFontSize...

Comment: Well, yeah but it was just a method suggestion, the value and the operations were random,. I said you can find the right ratio or value proportion by playing with both the height and not only trying to guess the font by the height, which is not absolute for a font

Comment: @Andrew21111 Thanks! I found a solution based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way has been tested

```swift
/// - Parameter height: target height for font
 func textFontSize(from height: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let defaultSize: CGFloat = 30
        let defaultFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: defaultSize)
        let boundSize = self.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : defaultFont])

        let pointsPerPixel = defaultFont.pointSize / boundSize.height
        let desiredPointSize = height * pointsPerPixel
        return desiredPointSize
    }
```